Does one say "die" (as an imperative) to express hostility?
I've been wondering if English uses "die" (imperative) to express hostility.
Background is, in Japanese, the literal "die" is often used as a sort of swear word, like "fxxk you" in English. For example, in a famous manga/anime Dragon Ball, most enemies say "die" to Goku the protagonist when attacking.
Also, "I'll kill you" is an expression that is used similarly in Japanese but I rarely hear in English. The only scene I remember is at the end of a movie Taxi Driver, the guy who was shot keeps shouting "I'll kill you" at Robert de Niro.
I'm not sure how to put it properly, these expressions in Japanese are just expressions of hostility rather than meant literally (although the Dragon Ball example above is more meant literally). Japanese has less swear words than English, and I feel they are sort of Japanese swear words.
Questions:

Is "Die!" or "I'll kill you!" used commonly (enough) to express hostility (in a sort of figurative manner)?
If it is used at all, are there any common situations where it is possible? (like, quarrel between kids or in real life-and-death situation or just in movies, etc.)
I recently saw Google's AI said to the user, "Please die", (source). Should I understand that this is just meant literally?


Some of us certainly say Why don't you just fuck off and die?, but plain Why don't you just die? doesn't cut it.

@FumbleFingers - I gather that people sometimes bully others on social media or in text messages by writing things like 'please kill yourself', and 'please die'.

"Drop dead!" might be used although it's not very common.

Note: we certainly can't explain why google's AI says stuff - that's off topic and should be asked on the AI forum.

We said "drop dead"  quite a lot when I was a student in an all-boys high school back in the 20th century; it meant something like "you're really annoying me" or "I don't give a flying f*ck what you think".  It was a retort.

@TimR - when my sister was 13 she said it to my dad a lot. He didn't comply, fortunately.

@MichaelHarvey How inconsiderate of him to continue to exist.

@StuartF To clarify, it is irrelevant to my question why AI says what it says. I'm asking how English speakers understand what it says.

@sundowner Can you figure it out from the rest of the article you linked? The article that quotes multiple people paraphrasing and reacting to the message?

"Die" and "I'll kill you" are always fundamentally literal. That's not to say the threats should be taken 100% seriously, but that is the basic intent, taken in context. Of course, they do get used sometimes in all the situations you mentioned.
Using them casually or allowing kids to do so can be divisive: socially-conscious people disagree on when, if ever, it qualifies as a joke or banter. If the threat is credible, it could even get you in legal trouble.
Take cues from the people around you, come to your own conclusions, and err on the side of not using it when in doubt.

I mostly agree, but it is very common for native speakers to use expressions related to death, e.g. My wife will kill me if I forget to buy laundry liquid or I'll just die if Liverpool don't win the cup.

I still say She's drop dead gorgeous! sometimes. But I've always preferred She's a stunner! (less "lethal", as in Star Trek Set phasers to stun, not vaporize).

@FumbleFingers - Doctor Johnson said that a certain smell that he encountered would 'stun an ox' and i used this at work about a stench from the toilet and got some very odd looks.
